# How to download youtube api jar for android

Tags: android, youtube-api

im trying to use youtube api codes but i cant find from where i download the correct jars.

I got to this page:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#YouTube_Data_API

I downloaded the file but i got there many jars and on the developers site its not wrinten which jars i should import.

I trired to import the file called: google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev77-1.17.0-rc from the root folder but when i try to use sample code eclipse cant find the imports.

The sample code is here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword

When im trying to use

```
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
```

Eclipse cant find from to import the files.

I dont understand why using youtube api should be so complicated. why not putting all the code on one simple jar.

Answer (score 2):

You basically need [Google Java client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list) to use Data API v3.

You can check [YouTube Direct Lite for Android project](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android) for all imports and best use cases for Android.

Also if you want maven, [YouTube Java samples](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-java) have maven examples.